# How can I get email notifications about new questions on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, email, subscriptions

How can I get notified by email about the new questions asked on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the upper right corner, click on the triangle icon next to your avatar. Select *Account settings*.
- In *Global account settings*, select in the left pane *EMAIL SETTINGS* → *Edit email settings*.
- Scroll all the way down. Select *All questions: Get notified whenever a question is asked on this Team. This setting will be unavailable if more than 25 questions are asked in a week.*: *ON*

---

[image: Select]

---

[image: Get notified whenever a question is asked on this Team]